Is JVM isolated from Kernal of Operating System?
I am  new in learning docker, I have read some articles about differences between virtual machine and containers and I understand that the VM isolated from kernel of OS, but a question popped in my mind says : if JVM is software virtual machine, does that mean it runs separately from the kernel? I might be misunderstanding the terms, but I have a simple question: Is the JVM isolated from the kernel?
I expect that it does, meaning it just convert java code to byte code, and it interact with the kernel as process, but I need more details and information if anyone could help.

It is just a process. It interacts with the kernel like any other application.

Don't confuse the term "Virtual Machine" as used for the JVM with "Virtual Machine" as used e.g. in VirtualBox.

Voting to re-open. This Question is valid, and seems focused enough. I imagine this issue could easily be a common misunderstanding given the terms involved. And we have a specific solid Answer already provided.

Java JVM is a process just like your applications.
The JVM is, in itself, a simulation of a machine (a virtual machine) that uses Java bytecode to perform tasks, as well as interpreters such as CPython.
In others words, it's an application like the others you've used, focused on interpreting a specific language, the bytecodes, just like the Python interpreter, separate from your kernel.
A Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is not a virtual machine in the sense of VirtualBox, VMware Fusion, and Parallels, etc. The JVM is not a hypervisor. And JVM is not a container in the sense of Podman and Docker.
